# If Lengthy operations are performed in onCreate and onStartCommand, can this lead to ANR? Also when exactly START_STICKY useful.?

Tags: android, service, android-anr-dialog, onstart

For android service, `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()` both run in main thread? OR onCreate runs in main thread and `onStartCommand()` runs in background thread spawned by the system itself?

Also putting lengthy tasks in `onCreate()` or `onStartCommand()` could lead to ANR?

Also incase of `START_STICKY`(return value for onStartCommand), intent is not redelivered if service is restarted after being killed. Then in what situations is it exactly useful(Any example)?